# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Would appreciate any help here.  I have this piece of code which is trying to update my State whenever a form field receives a change.  This worked fine in the previous version of React, but after upgrading to the latest version I'm getting the error "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance".

I understand that I need to normalize my State, which I plan to.  However, that will involve a significant refactor which I hoping to avoid at the moment with a quick fix.

**Error**

[image]

**Code**

```
handleMaterialTypeChange = (event, data) => {
    const material = this.state.controls.materials.materials;
    material[data.searchInput].material_type = data.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        controls: {
            ...prevState.controls,
            materials: {
                ...prevState.controls.materials,
                materials: [
                    ...prevState.controls.materials.materials[data.searchInput],
                    ...material
                ]
            }
        }
    }));
};
```

**State Example:**

```
state = {
    controls: {
        materials: {
            value: "",
            materials: [
                {
                    material_type: "",
                    material: ""
                }
            ],
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 10
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an exmaple of your state structure ? (And which variable this function changes)

Comment: The error means that you've got `...something` and `something` is not an array or something like an array

Comment: Yes.  Let me update the post with the state structure.

Comment: Not 100% sure but it looks like it should be `prevState.controls.materials.materials[data.searchInput],` without the `...`

Comment: probably should be `materials: [
                    ...material
                ]` Without the `...prevState.controls.materials.materials[data.searchInput]` since you're updating it on the top

Comment: @adiga That was the fix.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I have posted an answer. But you should probably accept @trincot's answer since it explains React-y way of doing things

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by

```
[...prevState.controls.materials.materials[data.searchInput],
```

because you cannot spread a non-iterable object within an array literal.

If you really want to keep with the "immutable" pattern, you should not do:

```
const material = this.state.controls.materials.materials;
material[data.searchInput].material_type = data.value;
```

Without the above *mutation* of the state, the altered *copy* can be made like this:

```
setState(prevState => ({
    controls: {
        ...prevState.controls,
        materials: {
            ...prevState.controls.materials,
            materials: Object.assign([], {
                ...prevState.controls.materials.materials,
                [data.searchInput]: {
                    ...state.controls.materials.materials[data.searchInput],
                    material_type: data.value
                }
            })
        }
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

your data structure is not easy to understand so I can not help you more than this example : https://repl.it/@Benoit_Vasseur/SO-Invalid-attempt-to-spread-non-iterable-instance

If I understood correctly you try to spread an object into an array so it does not work. You can spread an array in an array and an object in an object (type must match).

Hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this line: `...prevState.controls.materials.materials[data.searchInput]` because it's an object. Since you're already updating the `materials` array on top, no need to add another item.

You should change this part: `materials: [ ...material ]`

Here's some code that mimics `setState`

```js
handleMaterialTypeChange = (event, data) => {
  const material = state.controls.materials.materials;
  material[data.searchInput].material_type = data.value;

  setState(prevState => ({
    controls: {
      ...prevState.controls,
      materials: {
        ...prevState.controls.materials,
        materials: [
          ...material // here
        ]
      }
    }
  }));
};

const setState = (fn) => {
  console.log(fn(state))
}

const state = {controls:{materials:{value:"",materials:[{material_type:"",material:""}],validation:{required:true,minLength:10},valid:false,touched:false}}}

handleMaterialTypeChange(null, {searchInput: 0,value: "newMaterial"})
```

Update: This just fixes the error but @trincot's answer explains how to do this without mutation