# React Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, iterable, spread

I am trying to push a project to gh-pages, locally, everything works fine but when I upload it to gh I get this console error
"Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method."

```
const addToFavorites = (item) => {
    setFavorites([...favorites, item]);
    saveToLocalStorage([...favorites, item]);
  };
```

this piece of code seems to be the problem but I cannot figure it out

Comment: what is the type of `favorites` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463790/invalid-attempt-to-spread-non-iterable-instance)

Comment: in your code; "favorites" is not a array or is undefined. you should log your variable "favorites" in "addToFavorites" function to see whats the problem is.

Comment: const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]); this is the favorites array, it seems to be an object actually

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to say that your favorites array is not iterable and therefore it is not able to spread them into the array that you are creating in the arguments for setFavorites and saveToLocalStorage. Unless I take a look at your favorites array, I can't give you anymore information

Comment: const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]); this is my favorites array. As I stated, everything works perfect on localhost, the error is thrown at me after I access the project from github pages.

Comment: Can you try logging what the favorites object looks like in your addToFavorites function?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2Fv6UCL.png my console.log for favorites